# Azure function event hub integration with key vault reference

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am trying to integrate my Azure function to event hub and for that I need connection string. It works fine if I put the connection string directly into my application settings. However, I would like to keep my secrets in key vault and just use reference.

When I change the secret to reference I can see that the KV reference is fine and there is small green mark on top of it. However, when I go and look into function integrations it is completely broken and missing the integration. Also I cannot change to that application setting where my connection string is referenced in KV.

Is there any way to get the event hub integration working while referencing secrets from key vault?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if  you have followed to create an azure event hub triggered function with the environment variable and connection string .
Some app settings are to be made related to key vault.

- Create a system-assigned Managed Identity of your Function.
  (Function - > Identity -> Enable System-Assigned Managed Identity)
- Assign this Managed Identity GET access to your Key Vault in the
  Access Policies.
- Create a key vault identity - [Use Key Vault references - Azure App
  Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault)
- Create another app settings which are similar to above app settings
  which refer the key vault secrets as reference.
- A Key Vault reference is of the form
  @Microsoft.KeyVault({referenceString}), where {reference String} can
  be vault name or vault uri -[Use Key Vault reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax)

Or check the bindings of event hub trigger in functions.json  file [Azure function with Event hub trigger](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/azure-functions-event-hub-2603e8804f73)

Refer: [Getting Key Vault Secrets in Azure Functions](https://medium.com/statuscode/getting-key-vault-secrets-in-azure-functions-37620fd20a0b)  For
detailed information about the same.

Comment: I have followed the instructions and can create triggers successfully for other types of triggers. For event hub the KV integration just does not work similarly as for others.